# The Relative Layout doesn't cover the width of the screen

Tags: java, android, layout, android-relativelayout

I'm making an application that uses the relative layout to create a transparent black activity on the screen but the layout that it creates doesn't fit with the width of my phone screen.

Here's the result from my coding

[image: Screenshot https://ibb.co/w44WcWV]

Here's my xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#A6000000"
        >

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's the styles.xml that I use to create transparent activity

```
<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent = "android:Theme">
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    </style>
```

I have already set match_parent for both width and height. Thank you.

Comment: Device details please

Comment: huaweii vns-l22 with API level 23

Comment: above layout is Fragment or Activity?

Comment: try android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:alignParentBottom="true"

Comment: It’s a transparent activity that have layout over layout ( Relative )

Comment: @M.KJ How are you making your transparent activity? If it's as any kind of dialog, you're likely accidentally adding padding.

Comment: @JakeSteam I create the Theme.Transparent in the styles.xml and then use it in the manifest to the activity that I want

Comment: @AIMIN PAN it’s not wotking..

Comment: Have you checked the theme? Looks like a dialog theme to me.

Comment: @Charan Here's the code that I put in styles.xml                                                 <style name="Theme.Transparent" parent = "android:Theme">
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    </style>

Comment: @Charan and then in manifest I put this one on  <activity
            android:name=".GoogleCloudActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent">
        </activity>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set this in your `styles.xml` for your `Theme.Transparent`:

```
<item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
```

A floating window is usually a dialog, so has automatic spacing on either side. Setting this to false removes this automatic spacing. You can read a bit more about it [in the related documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#isFloating%28%29), specifically:

> ... whether this window is being displayed with a floating style (based on the `R.attr.windowIsFloating` attribute in the style/theme).

Although, if you're doing a fullscreen `RelativeLayout`, one wonders why you need transparency after all..!

Answer (score 3):

Change the style.xml with this.

```
 <style name="Theme.AppCompat.Translucent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">#33000000</item> 
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation</item>
    </style>
```

In Manifest

```
<activity
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Translucent"
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

I will go with Constraintlayout for single parent multiple view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#A6000000"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    </View>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: This wouldn't have solved OP's problem, the relative layout is already using the maximum available space.